# ECS Fargate Service with Multiple Target Groups. CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

Using the AWS CDK2 I would like to create an ECS Cluster, ALB and multiple Fargate services.  The Fargate services will have a task with two containers (beta, primary). Am I on the right track or would you suggest I do this differently?

I have had a few errors while trying different things. This is the latest message.

```
AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule Validation exception
```

I could use some advice on what I have built thus far.

```
export const createALBStack = ({
    app_name,
    app_props,
    domain_name,
    scope,
    vpc,
}: {
    app_name: string;
    app_props: cdk.StackProps;
    domain_name: string;
    scope: cdk.App;
    vpc: ec2.IVpc;
}) => {
    const stack = new cdk.Stack(scope, app_name + '-LOADBALANCER', app_props);

    // create a security group that allows all traffic from the same security group
    const security_group = new ec2.SecurityGroup(stack, app_name + '-SHARED-SG', {
        allowAllOutbound: true,
        vpc,
    });

    security_group.connections.allowFrom(security_group, ec2.Port.allTraffic());

    // security_group.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(443), 'Allow HTTPS Traffic');

    // security group for HTTP public access
    const public_http_security_group = new ec2.SecurityGroup(stack, app_name + '-PUBLIC-HTTP-SG', {
        allowAllOutbound: true,
        vpc,
    });

    public_http_security_group.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(80));

    // DNS

    const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(stack, app_name + '-ALB53-ZONE', {
        domainName: domain_name,
    });

    const domain_certificate_arn = `arn:aws:acm:${app_props?.env?.region}:${app_props?.env?.account}:certificate/${certificate_identifier}`;

    const certificate = acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(
        stack,
        app_name + '-CERTIFICATE',
        domain_certificate_arn,
    );

    const alb = new loadBalancerV2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(stack, app_name + '-ALB', {
        internetFacing: true,
        loadBalancerName: app_name + '-ALB',
        securityGroup: public_http_security_group,
        vpc,
    });

    const https_listener = alb.addListener(app_name + '-ALB_LISTENER', {
        certificates: [loadBalancerV2.ListenerCertificate.fromArn(certificate.certificateArn)],
        // defaultTargetGroups: [],
        open: true,
        port: 443,
    });

    https_listener.addAction(app_name + '-ALB_DEFAULT_RESPONSE', {
        action: loadBalancerV2.ListenerAction.fixedResponse(404, {
            messageBody: 'SEON DEVELOPMENT 404',
        }),
    });

    createHTTPSRedirect(app_name + '-ALB_HTTTPSRedirect', stack, alb);

    // Add a Route 53 alias with the Load Balancer as the target
    new route53.ARecord(stack, app_name + `-ALIAS_RECORD`, {
        recordName: app_name + `-ALIAS_RECORD`,
        target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53targets.LoadBalancerTarget(alb)),
        ttl: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
        zone,
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(stack, app_name + 'HTTP-LISTENER-ARN', {
        exportName: app_name + 'HTTP-LISTENER-ARN',
        value: https_listener.listenerArn,
    });

    return {
        alb,
        https_listener,
        security_group,
        zone,
    };
};
```

ECS Stack

```
export const createECSServiceStack = ({
    alb,
    app_props,
    cluster,
    containers,
    https_listener,
    scope,
    security_group,
    service_name,
    service_params,
    sub_domain,
    task_params,
    vpc,
    zone,
}: {
    alb: loadBalancerV2.ApplicationLoadBalancer;
    app_props: cdk.StackProps;
    cluster: ecs.Cluster;
    containers: TaskDefContainer[];
    https_listener: loadBalancerV2.ApplicationListener;
    scope: cdk.App;
    security_group: ec2.SecurityGroup;
    service_name: string;
    service_params: ServiceParams;
    sub_domain: string;
    task_params: FargateTaskDefinitionProps;
    vpc: ec2.IVpc;
    zone: route53.IHostedZone;
}) => {
    const stack = new cdk.Stack(scope, service_name, app_props);

    const task_role = new iam.Role(stack, service_name + '-taskrole', {
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'),
    });

    const task_definition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(stack, service_name + '-TASKDEF', {
        cpu: task_params.cpu,
        family: service_name + '-TASKDEF',
        memoryLimitMiB: task_params.memoryLimitMiB,
        taskRole: task_role,
        // runtimePlatform
    });

    const execution_role_policy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: [
            'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken',
            'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability',
            'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer',
            'ecr:BatchGetImage',
            'logs:CreateLogStream',
            'logs:PutLogEvents',
            'dynamodb:GetItem',
            'dynamodb:UpdateItem',
            'xray:PutTraceSegments',
        ],
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources: ['*'],
    });

    task_definition.addToExecutionRolePolicy(execution_role_policy);

    // can add more than one container to the task
    const sourced_containers = containers.map(container => {
        const containerPort = parseInt(container.environment.HOST_PORT);

        const ecr_repo = sourceECR({ ecr_name: container.name + '-ecr', stack });

        task_definition
            .addContainer(container.name, {
                environment: container.environment,
                image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(ecr_repo),
                logging: new ecs.AwsLogDriver({ streamPrefix: container.name }),
            })
            .addPortMappings({
                containerPort,
                protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
            });

        return {
            ...container,
            ecr: ecr_repo,
        };
    });

    const ecs_service = new ecs.FargateService(stack, service_name, {
        assignPublicIp: true,
        capacityProviderStrategies: [
            {
                base: 1,
                capacityProvider: 'FARGATE',
                weight: 1,
            },
            {
                capacityProvider: 'FARGATE_SPOT',
                weight: 1,
            },
        ],
        circuitBreaker: { rollback: true },
        cluster,
        desiredCount: service_params.desiredCount,
        maxHealthyPercent: service_params.maxHealthyPercent,
        minHealthyPercent: service_params.minHealthyPercent,
        securityGroups: [security_group],
        serviceName: service_name,
        taskDefinition: task_definition,
    });

    sourced_containers.map((sourced_container, index) => {
        const target_group = new loadBalancerV2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
            stack,
            sourced_container.name + '-tg',
            {
                deregistrationDelay: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
                healthCheck: {
                    healthyHttpCodes: '200,301,302',
                    healthyThresholdCount: 5,
                    interval: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
                    path: sourced_container.health_check_url,
                    port: sourced_container.environment.HOST_PORT,
                    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(20),
                    unhealthyThresholdCount: 2,
                },
                port: 443,
                protocol: loadBalancerV2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
                stickinessCookieDuration: cdk.Duration.hours(1), // todo ?
                targets: [
                    ecs_service.loadBalancerTarget({
                        containerName: sourced_container.name,
                        containerPort: parseInt(sourced_container.environment.HOST_PORT),
                    }),
                ],
                vpc,
            },
        );

        const target_rule = new loadBalancerV2.CfnListenerRule(
            stack,
            sourced_container.name + '-target-rule',
            {
                actions: [
                    {
                        targetGroupArn: target_group.targetGroupArn,
                        type: 'forward',
                    },
                ],
                conditions: [
                    {
                        field: 'host-header',
                        pathPatternConfig: {
                            values: [sub_domain],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'path-pattern',
                        pathPatternConfig: {
                            values: [sourced_container.url_path],
                        },
                    },
                ],
                listenerArn: https_listener.listenerArn,
                priority: service_params.priority + index,
            },
        );
    });

    const scaling = ecs_service.autoScaleTaskCount({ maxCapacity: 6 });
    const cpu_utilization = ecs_service.metricCpuUtilization();

    /*
     * scale out when CPU utilization exceeds 50%
     * increase scale out speed if CPU utilization exceeds 70%
     * scale in again when CPU utilization falls below 10%.
     */

    scaling.scaleOnMetric(service_name + '-ASCALE_CPU', {
        adjustmentType: aws_applicationautoscaling.AdjustmentType.CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY,
        metric: cpu_utilization,
        scalingSteps: [
            { change: -1, upper: 10 },
            { change: +1, lower: 50 },
            { change: +3, lower: 70 },
        ],
    });

    const pipeline = configurePipeline({
        cluster,
        service: ecs_service,
        service_name,
        sourced_containers,
        stack,
    });

    new route53.ARecord(stack, service_name + `-ALIAS_RECORD_API`, {
        recordName: sub_domain,
        target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53targets.LoadBalancerTarget(alb)),
        zone,
    });

    return {
        ecs_service,
    };
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking [CDK Construct library for higher-level ECS Constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns-readme.html) for working code samples. They also have many [TypeScript Examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript). You might want to check the [fargate-application-load-balanced-service](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/fargate-application-load-balanced-service/index.ts) sample code as a starting point.

Please point to any issues with a minimal reproducible example. Because now, it is almost impossible to understand what is wrong with your code. And why do you write need so much code instead of using [ECS patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns-readme.html)?